# Is there a function in R that will sum values based on Date of Year?

Tags: r, date, sum, posixct

I have a data table (Precip15) consisting of columns of precipitation, date of year (DOY), and Date_Time in POSIXct format. I need to be able to see the total precipitation (Rain_cm) for every day recorded. Any suggestions?

An example of the data table format looks like this:

```
DOY     Rain     Rain_cm    Date_Time
179      6         0.6      2019-06-28 15:00:00
179      0         NA       2019-06-28 15:15:00
179      2         0.2      2019-06-28 16:45:00
180      0         NA       2019-06-29 10:00:00
180      10.2      1.2      2019-06-29 10:15:00
180      2         0.2      2019-06-29 13:00:00
```

I need it to look like this:

```
DOY     Rain_cm    
179     0.8      
180     1.4
```

or possibly:

```
Date           Rain_cm
2019-06-28       0.8 
2019-06-29       1.4
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Yes, pretty easily. There are base R solutions, data.table solutions and dplyr solutions, among others.  In essence you need to 'boil down' your POSIXct to a Date and thne operate _grouped by date_.  My fave is data.table with `by=` command.  Maybe you can edit your post with a `dput()` output from your data.frame?

Answer (score 3):

Here are some base R solutions using the data frame `DF` defined reproducibly in the Note at the end.  Solutions based on dplyr, data.table or zoo packages would be possible as well.

**1) aggregate** `aggregate` on `DOY` or on `Date` (defined in the `transform` statement below) depending on what you want.  Note that `aggregate` automatically removes rows with NAs.

```
aggregate(Rain_cm ~ DOY, DF, sum)
##   DOY Rain_cm
## 1 179     0.8
## 2 180     1.4

DF2 <- transform(DF, Date = as.Date(Date_Time))
aggregate(Rain_cm ~ Date, DF2, sum)
##         Date Rain_cm
## 1 2019-06-28     0.8
## 2 2019-06-29     1.4
```

**2) rowsum**  Another base R solution is `rowsum` returning a one column matrix with the row names being the value of the grouping variable. `DF2` is from (1).

```
with(na.omit(DF), rowsum(Rain_cm, DOY))
##     [,1]
## 179  0.8
## 180  1.4

with(na.omit(DF2), rowsum(Rain_cm, Date))
##            [,1]
## 2019-06-28  0.8
## 2019-06-29  1.4
```

**3) tapply**  Another base R approach is `tapply`. This produces a named numeric vector.  `DF2` is from (1).

```
with(DF, tapply(Rain_cm, DOY, sum, na.rm = TRUE))
## 179 180 
## 0.8 1.4 

with(DF2, tapply(Rain_cm, Date, sum, na.rm = TRUE))
## 2019-06-28 2019-06-29 
##        0.8        1.4
```

**4) xtabs** `xtabs` can be used to form an `xtabs` `table` object. `DF2` is from (1).

```
xtabs(Rain_cm ~ DOY, DF)
## DOY
## 179 180 
## 0.8 1.4 

xtabs(Rain_cm ~ Date, DF2)
## Date
## 2019-06-28 2019-06-29 
##        0.8        1.4
```

### Note

The data in reproducible form is assumed to be:

```
Lines <- "DOY     Rain     Rain_cm    Date_Time
179      6         0.6      2019-06-28 15:00:00
179      0         NA       2019-06-28 15:15:00
179      2         0.2      2019-06-28 16:45:00
180      0         NA       2019-06-29 10:00:00
180      10.2      1.2      2019-06-29 10:15:00
180      2         0.2      2019-06-29 13:00:00"
L <- readLines(textConnection(Lines))
DF <- read.csv(text = gsub("  +", ",", Lines))
```

Comment: This is awesome, thank you! Oddly enough, I need to keep some NA's in the data. Essentially the entire data set is a few months worth, and some days obviously did not experience precip so the entire DOY shows up as NAs. I'd like to keep those so when the data is graphed I can see how precip occurred over the entire period.

Comment: (3) already does that. For (1) you can use `aggregate(Rain_cm ~ DOY, DF, sum, na.rm = TRUE, na.action = na.pass)`

Comment: Grotherndieck, this last code worked perfectly. Thank you for all your help folks!

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- tribble(
    ~DOY,     ~Rain,     ~Rain_cm,    ~Date_Time
    , 179      , 6         , 0.6      , "2019-06-28 15:00:00"
    , 179      , 0         , NA       , "2019-06-28 15:15:00"
    , 179      , 2         , 0.2      , "2019-06-28 16:45:00"
    , 180      , 0         , NA       , "2019-06-29 10:00:00"
    , 180      , 10.2      , 1.2      , "2019-06-29 10:15:00"
    , 180      , 2         , 0.2      , "2019-06-29 13:00:00"
)

df %>%
    mutate(Date_Time = ymd_hms(Date_Time)) %>%
    mutate(Date = as.Date(Date_Time)) %>%
    group_by(Date) %>%
    summarise(perDate = sum(Rain_cm, na.rm = TRUE))

  Date       perDate
  <date>       <dbl>
1 2019-06-28     0.8
2 2019-06-29     1.4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `aggregate` and `cut` functions to calculate your total daily precip values. The following code will provide you with the desired results:

```
precipTotals <- aggreate(df$Rain_cm ~ cut(df$Date_Time, breaks = "day"), x = df, 
    FUN = sum, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Make sure your precip columns are `as.numeric()` and your `Date_Time` is in `as.POSIXct()` format and this will work for you.